# Using Restored Variables Across Sessions Gives "uninitialized value" Error

Tags: tensorflow

I am restoring variables into a graph in one session, closing the session and then creating a new session where I attempt to evaluate the graph. When doing so I get the error `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value ...`.

Attempting to evaluate the graph in the first session works fine.

Calling `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` on the second session "fixes" the problem, however it resets the variables' values.

The initial restoration is done using:

```
meta_graph_def = meta_graph.read_meta_graph_file(meta_graph_filename)
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_graph_def)
sess = tf.Session(target=target, config=config)
saver.restore(sess, save_path)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq:

> What is the lifetime of a variable?
>
> A variable is created when you first run the tf.Variable.initializer operation for that variable in a session. It is destroyed when that tf.Session.close.

So it seems that the variable cannot be used across a `Session.close`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to restore the variables in each session.

Comment: Why is that? According to https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/variables: >Internally, a tf.Variable stores a persistent tensor. Specific ops allow you to read and modify the values of this tensor. These modifications are visible across multiple tf.Sessions, so multiple workers can see the same values for a tf.Variable.